# Related object not auto-filling parent object field

Tags: relationships, related-list

I have a custom object(Warranty Contract) with 2 related lists(Warranty Assets, Maintenance Contract).

When I am in the warranty contract, If i click on New Warranty asset on the related list, the record auto fills in the warranty contract that it is related to.

When I do the same for Maintenance contract this isn't auto-filling in. I've a feeling this must be a setting that I can change somewhere but i don't know where to look

These are both lookup relationships for the related lists

Comment: Go to the maintenance contract object and check if the new button has been overriden, or if you have a custom new button. The standard button should set the lookup properly. Also, are you in lightning or classic?

Comment: That was it, the new button was over-ridden by a VF page. I'm in classic

Comment: Cool so then if the VF page is doing stuff you need should be easy enough to modify it to pass in the parent Id, assuming it's a custom page y'all built. Or switch back to standard page if the VF page is not needed!